# Reading UTF-16 encoded XML file with XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, xml, xmlserializer

I am calling a WebService and get a string returned from a WebMethod. The string is an object serialized as XML that should be deserialized using the System.Xml.XmlSerializer.

My problem is that the first line indicates that the document is UTF-16 encoded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

So when deserializing, i get the error:

```
There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
```

It does work to do string.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8"), but there must be a clean method to let the XmlSerializer know?

Comment: As noted (see answer) that shouldn't cause a problem; can you show more of the code surrounding this? ideally a fully reproducible example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shouldn't affect anything - the following works fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("someType")]
public class Test {
    [XmlAttribute("hello")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
static class Program {   
    static void Main()     {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<someType hello=""world""/>";
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
        Test obj;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
            obj = (Test)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right, using a StringReader works just fine. My problem was that i took a detour, converting the string to a Byte[], wrapping it in a MemoryStream wrapped in an XmlTextReader - This is obviously much better, thanks.